# Bonded interface causes dropped packets

Tags: networking, centos

We're running CentOS 7.1 and have systems configured with dual NICs setup as a single bonded interface. When this bond is configured to use any of bond modes 1 5, or 6, we are seeing a substantial number of dropped packets. This is most easily observed using the ifconfig command:

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe3b:c2a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:3b:c2:a6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29449  bytes 1929707 (1.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14924  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 516  bytes 40394 (39.4 KiB)
```

Naturally, we expect to see some dropped packets, but we're seeing rates of 20% and more (the example above is 50%). That's well beyond what should be occurring with normal network traffic. Bond modes 2, 3, and 4 do not exhibit this kind of packet loss, but we do not want to use any of these. Our preference is bond mode 6, but bond mode 5 is acceptable as well.

Has anyone seen this level of dropped packets using a bonded interface in CentOS 7? We did not see this occur in CentOS 6.5. Our bond is setup using the following ifcfg-bond0 file:

```
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=6 miimon=100 updelay=12000 downdelay=0"
```

This is a pretty standard bond configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing this, too. Searching a few places online, it looks like there are other reports of this. I'd wager it's a cosmetic bug of some sort. Are you noticing anything bad happening at the application level? Might be worth running multiple netperf tests to see.

tl;dr -> It's cosmetic don't worry about it.

Comment: This is not an answer